# How to make a running total column in AG grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am coding a table in AG grid. My project is DRF and Reactjs

I'm trying to get a running total. to show up in a column. this si for accounting.

I can use valueGetter to do math using variables of the row I'm on eg.

```js
<AgGridColumn field="tax_debit"  headerName="Debit" flex={1} valueFormatter={currencyFormatter} />
                    <AgGridColumn field="tax_credit"  headerName="Credit" flex={1} valueFormatter={currencyFormatter} />
                    <AgGridColumn headerName="balance" flex={1} valueGetter="data.tax_credit - data.tax_debit" type="totalColumn" valueFormatter={currencyFormatter}/>
```

The issue is this is just doing the math on the row I'm on as you can see in the image. I want the first variable to the balance cell above the one I'm on then add credits then subtract debits.

[my code in action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FWcl.png)

So how do I get a reference of the cell above me? in the valueGetter

Comment: "I want the first variable to the balance cell above the one I'm on then add credits then subtract debit".  What does it means?

Comment: If this is a one off usage I would consider just doing it in code for simplicity (i.e. add a `runningTotal` property to the model, calculate it in js and add a column for it to the grid). Otherwise if you want it reusable in other grids you can consider creating a custom `valueGetter` which calculates the value on the fly.